# Intel RST/SRT + SSD cache: RAID

Tags: ssd, raid-1, intel-rst

I'm curious.  Is it possible to use Intel RST/SRT to do:

- RAID 1: SSD cache, composed of say 256 GB × 2 SSD configured as write-back
- RAID 1: HD subsystem, composed of say 4 TB × 2 HD

Such that the SSD cache sits in front of the HD subsystem, similar to how hybrid SSHD drives work?

Answer (score 1):

**Theoretically, yes. Practically, probably not due to an arbitrary limitation.**

- RST, as a hardware RAID, presents RAID volumes to the OS as if they were simple disks.
- SRT allows [to associate one SSD device and one HDD volume](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005501.html).

The unknown here is: *Will a RAID composed of SSDs be recognized by SRT as an SSD?*

- [SRT User's Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/chipsets/sb/intel_smart_response_technology_user_guide_3.pdf) (page 2) says that the accelerated volume can be *"HDD (or RAID volume)".* But for the SSD part, it only says *"the SSD to be used as a cache device,"* nothing about RAIDs.
- In a screenshot on the next page, we see, in a label to a radio button: *"SSD on port 1: XX GB"*. A RAID volume cannot be on a single port.

Comment: Although not preferred, making a single RAID 1 via two "hybrid/accelerated" channels would be acceptable.  I wonder if that would work?

Comment: @Malachi No. As I explained, RST works at lower level. RST creates the devices to work with. While SRT works with what has been created, and a "hybrid pair" is not recreated as a new hardware device. Also note that the accelerated entity is not a hardware device but a _volume._